# Is rebasing the best strategy to merge the branches

Tags: git, azure-devops, rebase, pull-request, merge-request

I have a parent branch and child branches.

when I want to merge a child branch into a parent branch , it's said that Re-basing the branch is the best way to merge.

If we're rebasing all the changes made in the other branch will come into the current child branch right ?

Then when someone wants to see what are the new changes made in the child branch will have the changes of the other branch too right.

Can someone throw some light on Rebasing vs Pull request vs Merge ?

I'm trying to find the best way go about merging the branches.

Comment: *"when I want to merge a child branch into a parent branch , it's said that Re-basing the branch is the best way to merge"* This, as a sweeping statement, is profoundly misleading. Rebase and merge are different operations, with different usages, and none does the other's job.

Comment: I thought rebasing gives good git history line diagram with the benefit of merging. where as merging is just merging the source code

Comment: Define "a **good** git history". What would it even mean? The only important characteristic of a *history* is to be truthful, or else it's just a story, pretty or not.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, based on my experience, if your scenario is the **team(multi people)** is developing the branches at the same time. Then `Rebase` will not suitable for that. Because if one of your colleague execute the `rebase`, it can modify all commits. Meanwhile, if another person is developing this branch, it is very likely that the public parent node could not be found, and the commit could not be submitted.

`rebase` can make the history more clear(one line), but `merge` not.

> Rebasing vs Pull request vs Merge

- **Pull request**

**Pull request** just used to raise a request to decide the way on how to "solve" commits between branches. After the pull request    raised, you can decide the strategy on which merge type you would    choose.

---

For better explain the **Rebase** and **Merge**, here I set the scenario first:

Assuming that you have two branches, **master** and **develop**. **develop** is the branch that is pulled from the **master** at (*3.added merge.txt file*)commit:

[image]

And now, set **HEAD** is at **6.added hello.txt file**, which is the most recent commit of the master branch.

- **Merge**

Based on the above scenario, execute `git merge develop`. Below is    the result shown:

[image]

The Git will do a **Three-way merge** automatically by following the    **common ancestor** of the two branches *(3.added merge.txt file)*, the latest commits of the two branches `(6.added hello.txt file)` and    `(5.added test.txt file)`. Then a new commit will generated based    from the modified content in the merge, that is, commit **7. Merge    branch 'develop'**.
       This is the effect of the `merge`, which simply merges the two    branches and generates a new commit.

- **Rebase:**

Also, based on the above scenario, execute `git rebase develop`.    Below is the result shown:

[image]

You can see that the **develop** branch and the fork are disappeared.

When performing a `rebase` operation, git will extract the    changes`(6.added hello.txt file)` from the current branch`(master)`,    and this changes is **start** from the common ancestor of the two    branches`(3.added merge.txt file)`.

Then let the master branch points to the latest commit`(5.added test.txt file)` of the target branch **develop** .  And apply the  changes which extracted just now to this latest commit.

If there are  multiple changes to the extraction, then git will be applied to the latest commit in turn. As shown in the following, left is the initial state, and right is the state after the implementation of **rebase**:

[image]

In one word, the `git rebase` extraction operation is a bit like `git cherry-pick`(just similar, but not same). After `rebase` executed, it    will cherry-pick the current commit sequentially, and then sent to    the target branch. After that, the extracted commit on the original    branch is deleted.

---

**Summary:**

You can see that the result of the `merge` can reflect the timeline, but `rebase` will disrupt the timeline. Both of them can all achieve code combined, just for public branch, like **master**, do not suggest use `Rebase`.

Also, the trouble for **merge** is roll back commit node. But for rebase is after **rebase** is finished, you will not know where you pulled out the development branch, this is what I mentioned disrupt the history timeline.

Comment: For a bigger team of 6 people what would be the preferred way of combining two branches.... Merge or rebase ?

Comment: @DanRam, **Merge** is better. This could keep a very completed history which benefit for team leader to check.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback :) I appreciate it. If you don't mind , why would merge be a better option than rebase ? I didn't the understand the term "Completed history which benefit for team leader to check"  do you mean teamleader can't check completed history if it's rebased ? I think even in rebase we get one git history line right ? for team leader to see ? I read somewhere if we rebase it may afftect the commits done by others as it would alter... so does that mean merge would not affect those previous commits ?

Comment: So far we have neve done any rebase and the project is running with Merge only but would it be a bad idea to move towards rebase now ?  could it alter previous commits ? is there any advantage rebase provides over merge command ?

Comment: @DanRam You could refer to the pics I shared in my answer. If I am a team leader, I want to clearly know the completed history about this repos. **Merge** can let me know "ohh, at node 7, someone create a branch from master and made 3 commits in that feature branch. Then merge them back at node 10", see second pic. Yes, **rebase** can also let me know the completed history. **BUT**, what it trouble brought is I will never know what happened on this repos before.I just know "oh, there are commits here". Not sure it is easily to understand, I think it's better if we can talk it with some pic.

Comment: @DanRam. For whether it is bad or good, this depend on your team. The advantage of Rebase is its history is very clean, it is a straight line. Also, if you want to roll back to some specific node, it would be very convenient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202865/discussion-between-dan-ram-and-merlin-liang-msft).

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to get experience using both [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and [merging](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). Then you will know what suits you best. It also depens on how many people are working on the project and their git knowledge. If they are not experienced with git usually merging is the best option.

Personally I prefer rebasing and keeping the repository history clean.

And, a pull request is a method of submitting contributions to a project and it is just a different thing from the ones mentioned above.

Comment: Hi , how pull request is different from Merge or rebase ? without doing any merge or rebase request...I'm able to Merge two branches using Pull request. Can you explain more please

Comment: There are 6 people working on the project. Would rebasing not preferrable for bigger team like this. If yes or no, could you please explain me the reasons

Comment: @DanRam, 6 people is a small team and can easily  go with the rebasing strategy. As for pull request this is just a mechanism to merge code *with review*, behind the scenes it is a simple merge. (and again, you can rebase your branch and create a pull request, not sure how to explain it, just try it with your own repository)